# Обновление fragment

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, мне надо после выбора элемента в spinner обновить картинку ImageView в моем фрагменте. Она обновляется если выйти и снова зайти, очевидно. А как это сделать сразу после выбора элемента? 
Или есть способ обновить саму картинку, без обновления фрагмента?

```
public class Table extends Fragment {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, null);
// инициализация данных, какие - то алгоритмы
...
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
          // обработчик нажатия, вот тут бы обновлять фрагмент

   }
}
//установка изображения
imgView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(namePic, "drawable",       v.getContext().getPackageName()));
..
 return v;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, картинки хранятся где-то в массиве вот так:

```
ArrayList<Integer> mImagesIds;
```

Тогда, в методе **onItemSelected** по индексу берешь элемент массива и выставляешь в качестве картинки:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          imgView.setImageResource(mImagesIds.get(position));
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало